# Send programmatically push notifications with react-native and amazon pinpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, push-notification, aws-pinpoint

Can someone provide an example to send push notifications programatically using react-native and amazon pinpoint?

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We request you to show your effort first, what you have done and tried so far. We can not answer direct question where there are no efforts. Hope you understand.